# R - Creating a crosstab with subtotals

Tags: r, crosstab, summarize, subtotal

I'm trying to make a crosstab with subtotals like the image below:
[image]

I can create a general table using summarise with the following code:

```
 ds %>%
    group_by(Division,Category) %>% 
      summarise(Total = sum(Headcount), 
                Female = sum(Headcount[Gender == "Female"]),
                FemaleP = sum(Headcount[Gender == "Female"])/total,
                Hispanic = sum(Headcount[Race == "Hispanic/Latino"]),
                HispanicP = sum(Headcount[Race == "Hispanic/Latino"])/total,
)
```

But I'm struggling to get subtotals for the division along with subtotals in the blue highlighted row in the screenshot. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much.

Comment: Loos similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104406/calculating-subtotals-in-r .

Comment: From what I understand the post linked shows how to calculate a total separately using the aggregate function but how do I splice it into my table. In particular the blue highlighted subtotal seems difficult to create.

Comment: The janitor package has some amazing crosstabulation abilities so a strategy of filtering for what you want and then splicing together the various outputs should be relatively easy.

Comment: I haven't found a way to have multilevel crosstabs using the janitor package, although it gets me close. Like I can't have it break the table out by Division and Rank on the row level.